# Chamar stub de uma procedure do Genexus no ambiente Java

Tags: java, genexus

Como chamar a stub de uma procedure do Genexus 15 em uma aplicação Java?

Stub no Genexus:

```
stub salvadados(in:&StringTeste, out:&StringRetorno)
    &StringRetorno = "ola " + &StringTeste
endstub
```

Após realizar o deploy da aplicação pelo Genexus e gerar o arquivo.jar, estou importando ele na minha aplicação Java usando NetBeans, e ele reconhece corretamente a procedure, porém eu não consigo acessar o método gerado para minha stub.

Minha classe Java: (no método `EnviaDados` há uma chamada para o método `gxep_salvadados`, que seria uma referencia para a stub que quero chamar, porém este nem outro método que o faça existe dentro da classe importada)

```
public class IntegracaoGenexus extends GXProcedure {

    ptesteintegracao ptesteintegracao; 

    public void executeCmdLine(String args[]) {
        execute();
    }

    public IntegracaoGenexus(int remoteHandle) {
       super(remoteHandle, new ModelContext(IntegracaoGenexus.class), "");
    }

    public IntegracaoGenexus(int remoteHandle, ModelContext context) {
       super(remoteHandle, context, "");
    }

    public void iniciar() {
        ptesteintegracao = new ptesteintegracao(remoteHandle, context); 

    }

    public void EnviaDados(String strDados) {
        ptesteintegracao.gxep_salvadados(strDados);
    }

    public void MostraDados() {

        //ptesteintegracao.gxep_mostradados();
    }

    public void execute() {
       execute_int();
    }

    private void execute_int() {
       initialize();
       privateExecute();
    }

    private void privateExecute() {  
       new ptesteintegracao(remoteHandle, context).gxep_salvadados("teste");
       cleanup();
    }

    public static Object refClasses() {
       GXutil.refClasses(IntegracaoGenexus.class);
       return new GXcfg();
    }

    protected void cleanup() {
       CloseOpenCursors();
       exitApplication();
    }

    protected void CloseOpenCursors() {
    }

    /* Aggregate/select formulas */
    public void initialize() {
       /* GeneXus formulas. */
       Gx_err = (short)(0) ;
    }

    private short Gx_err ;

}
```